# Getting the width of the contents of a td on a fixed table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table of data which I have previously set the widths of using jquery and the `table-layout: fixed` property in CSS. Later on in my code, the contents of the cells may change, possibly necessitating a change in width. The result is something like [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yUPET/1/)

As you can see, for long strings, the cell contents flow out of their containing cell and into the next cell over. What I'd like to do is check the contents of a cell after updating it to see if the width of the contents is greater than the cell. In my fiddle, there's a commented out line that does the width updating:

```
$('.firstItem').width(202) //successfully fits my entry
```

The problem is that the `202` is hardcoded in, and I don't seem to be able to figure out how to get it. I tried `.width()`, `.outerWidth()`, and `.innerWidth()` on the `td` that I'm trying to find the width of the contents of, but to no avail. I know that, if my contents are a `span` or something similar, I can call my width methods on that, but most of my contents are just text, and I'd rather not add more DOM elements, since my table is already on the large enough that it can slow things down side.

Is there a good way of getting the width of the text contents of a `td` in a `table`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yUPET/3/ - you could work on the `white-space` style to not wrap the long words that overflow

Comment: I'd like to keep the words together for readability, but just use javascript or jquery to update the widths of the cells to fit the contents. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Just set width auto on table:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yUPET/2/)

```
width: auto;
```

Or use textWidth snippet:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yUPET/5/)

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(text){
  var org = $(this)
  var html = $('<span style="postion:absolute;width:auto;left:-9999px">' + (text || org.html()) + '</span>'); 
  $('body').append(html);
  var width = html.width();
  html.remove();
  return width;
}

$('.firstItem').width($('td.firstItem').textWidth());
```

Comment: I'm syncing up the widths of the cells in two tables to make a fixed header, so I need to be able to manually set all of the widths of the cells, hence the width control.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your row an `id` and then use its `scrollWidth` property value and update this css rule to have your scrollWidth as width :

`th, td`

```
th, td{
border: 1px solid black;
width: 203px; /* your scrollWidth value here */
height: 20px;
}
```